# Impulse response for parallel RLC circuit

Tags: passive-networks

How to find out the Impulse response for parallel RLC circuit?

Comment: This is a very basic thing you should have been taught in class. So we can understand what you don't understand, please **edit your question** to tell us what you already know, what you think the answer might be, and why you think that your answer might not be correct.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to provide a schematic (even for simple circuit like this). For example, you haven't said if the impulse stimulus is a voltage impulse or a current impulse.

Comment: Find the step response and differentiate it.

Comment: This question can easily be found on the internet and in a textbook. Please reference to more convenient resources. If you don't understand something about it, then feel free to ask.

Comment: I could not find the question in the internet.

Comment: Okay, I'll give you subtle hint: Use the Laplace Transform. Instead of step response as your voltage/current source, try using an impulse response... \$ \mathscr{L}\{\delta (t) \} = 1 \$. That's the beauty of the Laplace Transform. That's why we use it for circumstances that require use to know the transient behavior of a circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is response, in the time domain, for Q = 10

[image]